# checking Check box in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Testing scenario goes like this:

I create some users eg. User EF, User GH, etc.

Now I need to select these Users from list of Users (Users are sorted alphabetically so newly created users are not always at top or bottom, depending on user name, they can be in between)

Now my developer is using unOrder list to display list of users.

HTML Code as under:

```
<DIV class="reflex-ssl-result-list "> 
<UL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title></LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>A</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>B</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>C</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>D</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>E</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>F</LABEL> 
<LI><INPUT value="" type=checkbox><LABEL class=reflex-search-result-title>G</LABEL> 
</UL> 
</DIV>
```

C and D are the newly created user and that is the one I need to select. How can I do this? I have tried xpath, but the issue is position of newly created user can be anywhere. If I was selecting user in the same location all the time, xpath is good for me, but in my scenario, I need something more than xpath.

Any suggestions?

Comment: None of the checkboxes have values or ids. How is the developer going to know which user is selected -  as none of the checkboxes have any unique characteristics!

Comment: That is the whole issue. It is not possible to give id's. because the list gets populated dynamically. If I create user with name say CA, the position of user D will move down one position and position of user D will be taken with user CA.

Comment: Added an answer. position should not matter as we can identify using label text.

Comment: If you are still facing difficulties, please follow up. Otherwise if an answer provided helped you resolve your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath to identify the label containing the text (eg: 'D'), go up one level to it's parent (the `LI`), and then select the `input` within.

```
//LABEL[.='D' and @class='reflex-search-result-title']/../INPUT
```

Since element tags in your example are in upper case, and Xpath case sensitivity can be an issue sometimes, check [How XPath Works in WebDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/XpathInWebDriver) to see what applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath

```
//label[contains(text(),'newly created user name')]
```

example:if you create user A

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'A')]")).click();
```

so where ever may be your user is created,you can click based on text and based on HTML tag.

Hope this helps you

-Aj

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>//input[@name='NAME']</td>
    <td>total</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.floor(Math.random() * ${total} )+1</td>
    <td>index</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//input[@id='NAME'])[${index}]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

XPaths:

E -- //label[text()='E']/preceding-sibling::input

F -- //label[text()='F']/preceding-sibling::input

G -- //label[text()='G']/preceding-sibling::input

H -- //label[text()='H']/preceding-sibling::input

Like Above XPaths You can click on the any Checkboxes to create combination of users

Please Let me know is my funda worked or not ?